# The Results SQL Doesn't Match Between Using Join and Without Join Tables -

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried to count groups without joining other tables and the command was like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM group 
WHERE deleted = 0
```

the result is `10`.

but, I tried to make an SQL command to count the group with join the other tables and the other tables are `member, user` and `profile`.
The SQL command that I tried:

```
SELECT count(group.gid) FROM group
JOIN member ON group.gid = member.gid
JOIN user ON member.uid = user.uid
JOIN profile ON users.uid = profile.uid
WHERE group.deleted = 0
```

the result is `25` and when I tried to give `LEFT JOIN`, the result is `0`.

Can I get the same result of SQL commands when I used the joining of the tables? or there are other ways to try it?

Thanks for the advice.

**Edited:**
I'm sorry my explain is not clearly before. here my reason why I want to join the tables.

I want to join the SQL because I want to get `id_dep` in the `profile`'s table. So, I will make SQL commands to get the total of the groups by id_dep where group.deleted = 0 i.e. 0 means the group is not deleted by users and 1 is already deleted by users.

Comment: SELECT count(DISTINCT group.gid) FROM group

Comment: Can not understand why `LEFT JOIN` has samll amount than `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Why do you join the other tables?

Comment: *the result is 25 and when I tried to give LEFT JOIN, the result is 0* This is **absolutely impossible**. Non-aggregated output for LEFT JOIN includes the output for INNER JOIN completely, hence COUNT with LEFT JOIN cannot produce the result which is less than one with INNER JOIN. I think that you make some non-mentioned edition or a misprint.

Comment: @Sergey I tried it but I got same the result is 0.

Comment: @lucumt I will learn about it again. thank you for your response.

Comment: @jarlh I want to get the total groups by the department which we can get departments from the `profile`'s table. I edited my post to the explain more.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.